# How to confirm if my AdMob is using test ads (not real ads)?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

In the [Native Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start) section it specifies:

> When building and testing your apps, make sure you use test ads rather
>   than live, production ads. Failure to do so can lead to suspension of
>   your account.
>
> The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit
>   ID for Native Advanced on Android:
>
> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110

However the ads that are being displayed could easily be passed as real ads so I'm wondering if there's a way to **confirm that they are test ads**.

First I use my real admob app id when initialising the MobileAds SDK:

```
<string name="admob_app_id">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
<string name="test_admob_app_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110</string>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id))
```

Then I use the native test id stated above in the `AdLoader`:

**MapFragment.kt**

```
private fun showAd(){
    val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(context, getString(R.string.test_admob_app_unit_id))
        .forUnifiedNativeAd { ad: UnifiedNativeAd ->
            /** Load image */
            val image = ad.images[0].drawable
            val options = RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()
            Glide.with(this).load(image).apply(options).into(firstImage)
            /** Load text */
            heading.text = ad.headline
            business.text = ad.advertiser
            subText.text = "Ad"
            val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.show(profile)
            transaction.commit()
        }
        .build()
    adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
}
```

The ad successfully loads but I'd like a way to confirm if it is a test ad, so I don't get my account suspended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, if you have used the correct `Ad unit ids` provided by Admob and the ad loads successfully, you will see an ad that that itself says that it is a test ad.

> The **quickest way to enable testing** is to use Google-provided test ad units. These ad units are not associated with your AdMob account, so there's no risk of your account generating invalid traffic when using these ad units.

So, if you use the provided test admob id, you should be loading test ads.

### OR

> Use your **own ad unit and enable test devices**. You can configure your device as a test device and use your own ad unit IDs that you've created in the AdMob UI.

[Quote source](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9388275?hl=en)

If you are initializing test ads, then you need to initialize them with test unit ids.

`MobileAds.initialize(context, context.getString(R.string.admob_test_unit))`

Where `R.string.admob_test_unit` is the test unit id.

Comment: Thanks I just tested this and I believe it's working - It shows the same generic ad about Saving money online/Saving money on credit cards. So right now in development I pass the test unit ID both when initialising the `MobileAds` SDK AND when building the `AdLoader`? And in production, I pass my actual AdMob app ID when initialising the `MobileAds` SDK AND when building the `AdLoader`?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the ad? The ad is supposed to be self-explaining. Yes, you need to pass same test unit IDs to both `MobileAds` and `AdLoader`. If you see the `AdLoader` example code on [the page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start), they have actually included a test unit ID, which is `"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110"`, same as `Native Advanced` unit ID on [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units)

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/DmHUxiB.jpg - right now I'm passing in the test unit IDs to both `MobileAds` and `AdLoader` like you said.

Comment: This is a sample code in `Kotlin` on how to implement a native ad, hope [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/kotlin/admob/NativeAdvancedExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/nativeadvancedexample/MainActivity.kt) helps.

Answer (score 1):

The "test" ads are marked as "test" when you see the add (there is a small banner on the ad itself). You can specify in your code which ad ID to use when in 'debug' or 'production' (release) mode as below:

```
String intersProd_ID="<production ad unit id here";
String intersTest_ID="<test ad unit id here>";
String useInters;
    if((BuildConfig.DEBUG)){
        useInters = intersTest_ID;
    }
    else{
        useInters = intersProd_ID;
    }
```